# Pixel Perfect это стандарт или ...

Tags: html, css

Возник вопрос по поводу Pixel Perfect - верстка по умолчанию должна быть 100% соответствовать макету или есть какие расхождения? В Тз должны об этом указывать?
Буду благодарен за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть такие заказчики (в основном зарубежные), что проверяю попиксельно. В наших регионах точность можно вариировать 95-100% (это называется хорошая верстка)